# How to add array of Objects of a class to List of type <x> where x is the same class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am have a class, say `X`.  I have created array of objects, and also a list of type of the same class.

eg:

```
public class Test : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    int a;
    String b;
    [DataMember(Name = "a", IsRequired = false, Order = 1)]
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { value = a; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "b", IsRequired = false, Order = 2)]
    public String B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { value = b; }
    }
}
```

The object array is created like

```
Test[] test1 = new Test[2];
List<Test> test2 = new List<Test>();
test1[0].a = 1;
test1[0].b = "t";
test1[1].a = 2;
test1[1].b = "y";
test2.add(test1);
```

This line:

```
test2.add(test1);
```

is not working.  The error is

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Have you debugged your application?

Comment: The posted code should not show that error. It ought to complain about `Test` vs `Test[]`

Comment: Yes. See the code is complex. Am not able to depict the whole thing. What i have mentioned here is a model. Thanks

Comment: The mode is not sufficient. Creatre a small app and create something that does give the same error and compiles.

Comment: This creates the same error.

Comment: No it doesn't. Not on the same line anyway. You have introduced new errors and turned this in a goose chase.

Comment: the second `C` in [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) stands for **Correct**.  When you make your sample, you should try compiling and running it and making sure that it indeed does represent your problem

Answer (score 9):

`test1[0]` is `null`.
You need to create an instance before you can set its properties.

Also, you can only `Add()` a `Test[]` to a `List<Test[]>` (a list of arrays).

If you want to add all of the objects in the array, call `AddRange()`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your code like this

```
Test[] test1 = new Test[2];
List<Test> test2 = new List<Test>();
test1[0] = new Test();   //initialized here 
test1[0].A = 1;
test1[0].B = "t";
test1[1] = new Test();  //initialized here 
test1[1].A = 2;
test1[1].B = "y";
test2.AddRange(test1);  // Use Add range method
```

Answer (score 0):

First: The Tests in the array need to be instantiated.

Second: You can only add an array to a list by using AddRange()

```
Test[] test1 = new Test[2] {
    new Test(),
    new Test()
};
List<Test> test2 = new List<Test>;
test1[0].a = 1;
test1[0].b = "t";
test1[1].a = 2;
test1[1].b = "y";
test2.AddRange(test1);
```

Comment: `test1[0].a` will still throw null reference exception.

Comment: -1 for the same reason as Rohit

Comment: @RohitVats what did I miss?

Comment: You have edited the answer. In earlier implementation you are initiating members of `test2` instead of `test1`.

Comment: @DennisTraub you need to edit, in order to remove my vote. :)

Comment: @DennisTraub i have removed mine. I guess he saw that this is downvoted so he did as well. :)